# Angular Ag-Grid: Add PrimeNg P-dropdown as html element in Ag Grid cells

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

How to include basic HTML elements in Ag-Grid cells.

Below is my html PrimeNg p-dropdown in `MyComponent.html`

`<p-dropdown [options]="cars" [(ngModel)]="selectedCar" (click)="doSomething()" [style]="{'width':'150px'}"></p-dropdown>`

And ag-grid now to be used to include above p-dropdown in one of the cells

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 350px;" class="ag-theme-alpine"
[gridOptions]="gridOptions"
[rowData]="rowData"
[columnDefs]="columnDefs">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

And below is the code in `MyComponent.ts`

```
 this.columnDefs= [{
    headerName: 'Type',
    field: 'type',
    editable: true
   },
   {
    headerName: 'DropdownColumn'
    field: 'ddValue',
    cellEditor:'agRichSelectCellEditor',
    cellEditorParams: function(params) {
    
    },
    cellRenderer: function(params) {
     'What to do here'
    }
]
```

How to include any HTML elements of Angular(including ng-model + click functions) in any Ag-Grid cells

Answer (score 5):

If you want complex HTML inside AgGrid the cells, then it's time to use cell renderers.

You need to define a custom component that will implement `ICellRendererAngularComp` interface and receive the value of a cell through the `agInit` method.

**prime-ng-dropdown.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from "ag-grid-angular";
import { ICellRendererParams } from "ag-grid-community";
@Component({
  selector: "app-prime-ng-dropdown",
  templateUrl: "./prime-ng-dropdown.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./prime-ng-dropdown.component.css"]
})
export class PrimeNgDropdownComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  params: ICellRendererParams;

  cars = [
    { label: "Honda", value: "eHonda" },
    { label: "Jaguar", value: "fJaguar" },
    { label: "Mercedes", value: "gMercedes" }
  ];

  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    this.params = params;
  }

  onChange(value) {
    this.params.data[this.params.colDef.field] = value;
  }

  refresh() {
    return true;
  }

  doSomething() {}
}
```

**prime-ng-dropdown.component.html**

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cars" [ngModel]="params.value" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
    (click)="doSomething()" appendTo="body"
    [style]="{'width':'150px'}">
</p-dropdown>
```

Now that we have our component, we need to tell ag-Grid about it. All custom components should be listed in `frameworkComponents` configuration option. So let’s import our custom cell renderer and specify it in the configuration:

**app.component.ts**

```
frameworkComponents = {
  primeNgDropdown: PrimeNgDropdownComponent,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remember this framework key
};
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ag-grid-angular
  ...
  [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
```

Also, you have to pass this component to `AgGridModule.withComponents` call:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
      ...
      AgGridModule.withComponents([PrimeNgDropdownComponent])
    ],
```

Finally, you only need to specify which component to use for your column through specifying framework key in cellRenderer option:

```
columnDefs = [
  ...
  {
    headerName: "DropdownColumn",
    field: "ddValue",
    cellRenderer: 'primeNgDropdown' <----------------- this one
  }
];
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-install-and-simple-example-angular-7-ooqhhv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: this really helped me know more...:) @yurzui One doubt since i cannot create a custom component separately for p-dropdowns, i have all 5 p-dropdowns in the same Page and i just need to replace it with Ag-Grid. What to do now in this case ??

Comment: I didn't get your requirement. Do you want to change cell template or replace dropdowns with grid?

Comment: One page having 9 p-dropdowns, I just need to put them in Ag-Grid. In short replace them with Ag-Grid. But as per your soln I had to create 9 seperate components, which is not possible for me