# multiple dropdowns in a ag-grid array

Tags: angular, ag-grid, primeng

hey there i wish you all doing great.
i have a issue with primeng dropdown inside a ag-grid table.
my code is like this.

```
 uwproles=[
            [
                {label:"value1",value:"value1"}
            ],
            [
                {label:"value2",value:"value2"},
                {label:"value3",value:"value3"}

            ],
            [
                {label:"value2",value:"value2"},
                {label:"value3",value:"value3"},
                {label:"value4",value:"value4"}
            ]
        ]
```

and here is my html.

```
<div *ngFor="let row of uwproles;let i=index" >
<p-dropdown [options]="row" [ngModel]="params.value" 
     appendTo="body"
    [style]="{'width':'80%'}">
</p-dropdown>
</div>
```

this component is defined as a cellRenderer Component in a ag-grid array as explained in this poste
[Angular Ag-Grid: Add PrimeNg P-dropdown as html element in Ag Grid cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63102882/angular-ag-grid-add-primeng-p-dropdown-as-html-element-in-ag-grid-cells)

but as a result it give me this

[image]

it's read juste the first item in the array and display it in all the dropdowns.
i wannt every drop down to display it's own options.

Comment: Hard to say without the code. You are iterating over uwproles array but attaching always the same `[ngModel]`. Maybe this is the reason? `[ngModel]` should be unique for every dropdown. Try to connect it with index `i`.

Comment: @KarolTrybulec no the ngModel binding is not the probleme i had connect it with the row index but always the same probleme,it's like the ngFor is not doing it's job it's not iterating over the uwproles array,it read just the first element of it and its stop

Comment: Please demonstrate your in a Plunker or Stackblitz.